# Getting the names of inputted vectors to an R function

Tags: r, function

I was wondering how I could have my R function `foo` return the names of the vectors that are inputted to it?

In this example, I want `foo` to return `"a"` and `"b"`.

Here is what I tried without success:

```
a = 1:30 ; b = 50:60   # the inputted vectors

foo <- function(...){  # the function

 L <- list(...)
 names(L)
}

# Example of use:
foo(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `substitute` as shown gives a pairlist of symbols and `deparse` applied individually to each element converts each to a character string:

```
foo <- function(...) sapply(substitute(...()), deparse)
foo(a, b)
## [1] "a" "b"
```

Comment: Apparently, `substitute(...())` suffices except that it gives a list.

Comment: I did mention that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo <- function(...) as.character(substitute((...)))[-1]

foo(a, b)
# [1] "a" "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `match.call`

```
foo <- function(...) sapply(as.list(match.call())[-1], as.character)
foo(a, b)
#[1] "a" "b"
```